# Is there an alternative (instead of using Opacity) to obtain a clear parts for the overlapping area of three RegionPlots?

Tags: plotting, bugs, plot-themes, opacity

I want to combine three `RegionPlot`, and I need to do this in a way such that the overlapping and intersection parts of the plots are visible and clear. I use this code and use `Opacity` for their colors

```
p1 = RegionPlot[x - y < 0, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6},  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]], BoundaryStyle -> None];
p2 = RegionPlot[2 y - x < 0 , {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6},   PlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Opacity[0.2]], BoundaryStyle -> None];
p3 := RegionPlot[y Sin[x] < 0 , {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6},    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]], BoundaryStyle -> None];

Show[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

when I save the result as PDF, there are these grid line polygons (as the picture attached). According to the other similar problems in SE, this is a bug.

**Question**
Is there an alternative way to obtain this overlapping result without using `Opacity`? So that the result it gives is a clear plain color?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cond = {x - y < 0, 2 y - x < 0, y Sin[x] < 0};

colors = {LightBlue, LightGreen, LightRed};

gr2 = RegionPlot[Evaluate[Join[cond, And @@@ Subsets[cond, {2}]]],
  {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 6},
  PlotStyle -> Join[colors, Blend[#, 1/2] & /@ Subsets[colors, {2}]],
  BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/gr2.pdf", gr2];

Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/gr2.pdf"][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. But if the three conditions are not that simple; say each $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$ need to be used with very high precision separately, accordingly, the only way is to use Show to combine them; in that case, is there any alternatives? @Bob Hanlon

Comment: I don't think it is a precision issue. If there are overlaps between more than two regions in an area, the determination of the appropriate colors becomes more involved. I don't know of any method using `Show` that doesn't have the problem you are trying to avoid.